# Preventing race-condition on model creation with limit validation on has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Given the following models and MySQL InnoDB tables:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :user
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  MAX_THINGS_PER_USER = 5

  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :things

  # some other validations which read from the DB
  # ...
  validate :thing_count_within_limit, on: :create

  def thing_count_within_limit
    if self.user.things.count >= MAX_THINGS_PER_USER
      errors.add(:base, "Exceeded thing limit")
    end
  end
end
```

When I create 2 `Thing` instances at (almost) exactly the same time for a given `User` who has already 4 `Thing` instances, to my understanding it can happen that the `User` can end up with 6 `Thing` instances, because the creation including validation are wrapped in a transaction and the first DB read inside this transaction creates a snapshot view on the DB, because the default read mode is `READ REPEATABLE`. This can cause that both validations inside their respective transactions read a count of 4, thus both creations are valid and both `Thing` instances are stored in the DB, leaving the `User` with 6 instances which is not desired.

**What is the preferred way to overcome this race condition?**

My approach was to lock on the associated `User` model:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def save_with_lock
    self.user.with_lock do
      self.save
    end
  end
end

class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def create
    @thing = current_user.things.new #current_user is a User
    if @thing.save_with_lock
      redirect_to @thing
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you find any other way to doing this?